# Is the following figure DAG?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, dag

I have been through multiple definitions of DAG and all of them say that it is a directed graph without cycles. Also, it is said that it has topological ordering.

Now the following figure is directed graph and does not have cycles.

[image]

But looking at the ordering of edges (look at edge (2,1)), it is not topologically ordered.

Is this still a DAG or every edge must be topologically ordered for this graph to be a DAG??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The acronym *DAG* stands for [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). In other words, a DAG is a (finite) digraph without directed cycles. A digraph is a DAG if and only if it has a topological ordering.

In your example you have a labeled DAG. The labels do not constitute a topological ordering of the DAG, but the underlying digraph is still a DAG.

Comment: cannot upvote because of less reputation, but it was the answer i was searching for.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer.

Comment: I prefer the term "acyclic directed graph" (ADG) for what is commonly called a directed acyclic graph (DAG) because it seems a more accurate description. I suspect that DAG is more popular only because it is easier to pronounce in English.